# (VB.Net) How to let a service search for a specific application running on the logged-on user's desktop

Tags: vb.net, service, desktop-application

I have a service that will be installed by admin for users. I'm assuming that the service account must be LocalSystem for it to do its job: it must loop through all applications with a MainWindowTitle opened by the logged-on user, and close a particular one if found.

I can loop through the logged-on user(s) using the 'explorer' process and find the username(s). What I have difficulty with, is loopging through the applications that the active user has open.

I'll appreciate any help in the direction how to let a service get access to the active logged-on user's destkop so that it can loop through its running applications.

Thanks in advance.

I can't find anything that can help me figure this out! A lot of Googling en ChatGPT didn't help :-(

**EDIT 1**

The service can enumerate all running processes (os, services, user(s)), but i can't get the MainWindowTitle associated with them

**UPDATE 1**

There seems to be a workaround. See a solution posted here:

[Using a vb.net application running as SYSTEM, how do I start a detached process for each logged on user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188988/using-a-vb-net-application-running-as-system-how-do-i-start-a-detached-process?rq=2)

I still have to do more tests, but so far the proposed method by @user1932998 in the thread mentioned above seems to work. It comes down to the following:

- **my original situation**

1. monitor-executable, launched normally and locally, finds the 'forbidden' app window throught MainWindowTitle search loop and closes it. No problem.
2. monitor-executable, launched by the service, inherits the same restrictions of the service: no access to the user's deskstop running applications MainWindowTitles. Useless.

- **using @user1932998's method**

3. monitor-executable, lauched by the service, behaves the same as if launched normally and locally :-) If the user closes the monitor-executable, the service just launches it again. Service is stop-proof so can't be shut down by the user. Monitor-executable may be killed, but the service just gives birth to a new one right away.

So far I've been able to replicate the scenario promoted by @user1932998. He/she uses [sc.exe] internally for installation. I've used [installutil.exe] and had similar success :-)

All these tests are done on my machine. I need Admin to confirm my findings. I'll come back with a final update..

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to build this yourself? Windows has [WDAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/windows-defender-application-control/wdac) built in where admins can then *whitelist* allowed apps, and you don't have to do something as crude as searching application window titles to prevent bad executables from running.

Comment: Service typically don't interact with the Desktop (window = parent of all other windows). So I doubt enumerating Window captions will work. Why not [enumerate the running processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=net-8.0) and [determine their owner](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aeff7e41-a4ba-4bf0-8677-81162040984d/retrieving-username-of-a-running-process?forum=netfxbcl)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The reason i'm building it myself is because the application window i want to close is one of many its many child windows. The app is allowed to run by anyone. Admin has to let everybody to be able to launch it. It's a few specifiek child windows that i want to be able to close.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The process MainWindowTitle displays the active child window and when that matches what the service is looking for, that child window need to be closed.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Eumerating running processes from the service gives me only running processes in the service domain. Explorer.exe is also on the list and with that, i can get the username of the user involved. But that's all i get. The service needs to see what apps that user has running and that's where i'm stuck.

Comment: *The app is allowed to run by anyone. Admin has to let everybody to be able to launch it. It's a few specifiek child windows that i want to be able to close.* Well that sounds like the job of the actual application itself, via application security, rather than trying to hack processes at the OS level. And how would you know if the application would remain stable when windows just disappear? Sounds like an XY Problem to me.

Comment: @HardCode The application itself can't do it, and the party that has created the application has been notified. It has been established that closing some child windows will shut down features presented by those windows only, and that the rest of the application will be just fine. Application creator has no time/resources to implement this so my service is the only way we all agreed to do it.